# Rename multiple folders, using regex

Tags: rename, regex, batch-rename

As the title says, I'm looking for a command / tool - preferably something running from the terminal (I'm using Ubuntu on a remote server), that can replace a specific part of multiple directories at once. The folder structure is like this:

```
Example.of.Structure[app]

Another.Example[app]

Third.Example.of.Structure[app]
```

And I want to rename all of the folders, so the [app] part gets removed from the names of the folders.

I've tried dabbling with basic RegEx. Matching the square brackets, and the text inside it.

Which seems to work fine, when I use it for ["finding it"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/crnYb.png) - but I'm really unsure how to put it into a command.

The regex I came up with, to find the text inside the brackets (including the brackets themselves) was: `\[\w+\]`

But how do I put this into a command?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you ever used `vi` (or `vim`)?  If so it'll be easy; otherwise have a look at https://askubuntu.com/questions/428669/i-cannot-rename-files-in-bulk-using-ubuntus-rename-feature  (ie. use the `rename` command)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't really need a regex for this. A simple shell glob plus parameter expansion will do it:

```
$ for f in *\[*\]/; do echo mv "${f}" "${f/\[*\]}"; done
mv Another.Example[app]/ Another.Example/
mv Example.of.Structure[app]/ Example.of.Structure/
mv Third.Example.of.Structure[app]/ Third.Example.of.Structure/
```

(remove the `echo` once you are happy that the proposed replacements are correct).

If you want to use a regex based tool, then the perl-based `rename/prename` is the obvious choice:

```
$ rename -n 's/\[\w+\]//' */
rename(Another.Example[app]/, Another.Example/)
rename(Example.of.Structure[app]/, Example.of.Structure/)
rename(Third.Example.of.Structure[app]/, Third.Example.of.Structure/)
```

(remove the `-n` once you are happy that the proposed replacements are correct).

Both of these match the *first* occurrence of the pattern. If there's a possibility that the `[app]` pattern can occur elsewhere, look at anchoring the match to the end of the pattern. See [Start of String and End of String Anchors](https://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html)

Comment: How do you use this with references? I want to change all folders containing the Year at the end to move it to the beginning like "Abba - Arrival(1976" -> "1976 - Abba - Arrival"